Need help to solve Sturm-Liouville ODE of form $\frac{dy}{dx}\Big(p(x)\frac{dy}{dx}\Big) + (\lambda)w(x)y = 0$
The first bit of information is just to provide context for where the equation I need help with came from, if you are uninterested, you can just skip to equation (2).
While solving a Poisson's Equation with Dirichlet BCs using a Laplacian in spherical coordinates (with $\theta$ and $\phi$ being our azimuthal and polar angles) along a surface of constant $\textbf{r}$, I noticed after using method of separation of variables by assuming a trial solution $u(\theta,\phi) = T(\theta)P(\phi)$ with BCs $\cases{T(0) = 0, T(H) = f(\phi) \\ P(0) = P(L) = 0}$ and plugging this into our Laplace's Equation in spherical coordinates with constant $\textbf{r}$ gives:
$$\frac{P''}{P} = \frac{\sin(\theta)T'-\cos(\theta)^2 T''}{T}= -\lambda$$,
that I ended up with 2 Sturm-Liouville equations. For $P(\phi)$ we have a simple one: $P'' + \lambda P = 0$ which given the homogeneous BCs on both ends, we can simply use the eigenfunction and eigenvalue $P(\phi) = \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}), \lambda = \Big(\frac{n\pi}{L}\Big)^2$.
The resulting ODE for T however, is $T(\theta)$, $\sin{\theta}T' - \cos(\theta)^2 T'' + \lambda T = 0$, which can be rewritten by factoring out $-\cos(\theta)^2e^{sec(\theta)}$ as:
$$\tag{1}e^{-\sec(\theta)}T''-\tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)e^{-sec(\theta)}T'-\lambda\sec(\theta)^2e^{-\sec(\theta)}T=0$$ which undoing chain rule gives:
$$\tag{2}\frac{d}{d\theta}\Big(e^{-sec(\theta)}\frac{dT}{d\theta}\Big) - \lambda\sec(\theta)^2 e^{-sec(\theta)}T=0; T(0) = 0, T(H) = f(\phi)$$
and substituting $\theta=x,T = y,e^{-\sec(\theta)} = p(x), e^{-\sec(\theta)}\sec(\theta)^2 = w(x)$, we get $\boxed{\frac{dy}{dx}\Big(p(x)\frac{dy}{dx}\Big) + (\lambda)w(x)y = 0}$, which is a much more complicated Sturm-Liouville problem than was for $P(\phi)$, and I do not know how to begin setting up the general solution for this more complicated problem. Looking around for literature on this specific form of the the problem ($p(x) \ne 1, w(x) \ne 1$, and $q(x) = 0$) hasn't helped much. Could someone provide the general steps for how to work towards a general solution? Is this ODE solvable?

NOTE: Technically with the first ODE we have identified $\lambda$, so we can substitute that into (2) and there is no longer a need to worry about solving for it.
